# How do i disable the automatic date time in an azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, windows-8, azure-virtual-machine

I want to be able to change the date and time on my vm to dates in the past.  Every time I change it, it automatically changes back because of this setting.  Unfortunately I cannot change it because it is disabled.  I am logged in as an admin on the vm.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't belong on StackOverflow, as it's not programming-related. Maybe try on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Hyper-V Time Synchronization Service, startup set to "Manual"
- Windows Time Service, startup set to "Manual"

BUT based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/07/29/manage-timezone-for-applications-on-windows-azure.aspx) article, it 's not recommended so maybe the safest way is to add time offset in you program

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem

Comment: This did not work.  I've also posted this on serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/745179/how-do-i-disable-the-automatic-datetime-in-an-azure-virtual-machine.  I'm not sure how to close this question here.